# The operator * is undefined for the argument type(s) double, EditText

Tags: java, android, operators

I'm really not sure why I get this error. It's probably something simple but I'm new to this.

```
final Button calculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculate);
calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        // Implement the OnClickListener callback       
        private void onClick(Button calculate) {
                double perimeter = 2 * (Math.PI * entry); //error on this line
                System.out.print(perimeter);

                }

        public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        }

    );
```

Comment: What is the reason the `onClick` method receives a parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would appear that `entry` is an `EditText` object ... you can't multiply that.

I'm going to make an educated guess that you want to multiply what's *in* that `EditText`. Looking at the javadocs, You need to get the text with `entry.getText().toString()`, and convert it to a numeric type (provided the text represents a numeric type).

```
double myInputDouble = Double.parseDouble(entry.getText().toString());
```

(or `Integer.parseInt()` if that's what you're expecting)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html