# The operator * is undefined for the argument types [][]array, double

Tags: java, arrays, error-handling, project

I'm working on a project that will do a simple contrast of an image, I have already scanned through the arrays to find the min and max values but now I have to paint the image.

I keep getting this error "The operator * is undefined for the argument type(s) drawingpanel, double"

here is the code

```
    public void simple (Graphics g) {
    if (DrawingPanel.imageArray != null) {
        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();
        int hPos = (width - DrawingPanel.imageArray[0].length) / 2;
        int vPos = (height - DrawingPanel.imageArray.length) / 2;
        for (int r = 0; r < DrawingPanel.imageArray.length; r++)
            for (int c = 0; c < DrawingPanel.imageArray[r].length; c++) {
                newc = Math.round(maxshade * ((double)(DrawingPanel.imageArray[r][c] - minshade) / (maxedshade - minshade))); //error here!!!
                g.setColor(new Color(DrawingPanel.imageArray[r][c], DrawingPanel.imageArray[r][c], DrawingPanel.imageArray[r][c]));
                g.drawLine(c+hPos, r+vPos, c+hPos, r+vPos);                     
            }
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawRect(hPos, vPos, DrawingPanel.imageArray[0].length, DrawingPanel.imageArray.length);                  
}
```

}

Any help would be appreciated.. thanks!

also this is where i compute my min maxes...

```
    public static void computeImageStatistics(DrawingPanel array) {
        DrawingPanel.array = carray;
            maxedshade = carray[0][0];      
            for (int i = 0; i < carray.length; i++) {
              for (int j = 0; j < carray[i].length; j++) {
                if (carray[i][j] > maxedshade) {
                  maxedshade = carray[i][j];
                }
              }
            }
            minshade = carray[0][0];    
            for (int i = 0; i < carray.length; i++) {
              for (int j = 0; j < carray[i].length; j++) {
                if (minshade > carray[i][j]) {
                    minshade = carray[i][j];
                }
    }
            }
    }
```

and some other variables in my DrawingPanel..

```
     public void showImage(File fileName) {
        Scanner scan;
        try {
            scan = new Scanner(fileName);
            typefile = scan.next();
            iname = scan.next();       
            width = scan.nextInt();
            height = scan.nextInt();
            maxshade = scan.nextInt();
            array = new int[width][height];

            for(int r = 0; r < array.length; r++)
                for(int c = 0; c < array[r].length; c++)
                    array[r][c] = scan.nextInt();
            imageArray = array;
            repaint();              
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

 }
```

Comment: similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237946/the-operator-is-undefined-for-the-argument-types-double-edittext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error msg tells you can not use the operator '*' between `maxshade` and `((double)(DrawingPanel.imageArray[r][c] - minshade) / (maxedshade - minshade))`. Because maxshade is type of `DrawingPanel` , NOT a numeric(double/long/float/int...).

As I look into your 2nd code block,I see a static variable name `maxedshade` .It seems like a numeric.

And then I look into your error line:

```
newc = Math.round(maxshade * ((double)(DrawingPanel.imageArray[r][c] - minshade) / (maxedshade - minshade))); //error here!!!
```

Did you made a input mistake on "**maxshade**" ? Should it be **maxedshade** ?